# Generate Link in Search bar in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am in the process of generating the link in the Twitter bootstrap search bar. This is what I did but it is not generating any link.

```
<div> 
 <form class="form-search"> 
    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
     <% @shops.each do |shop| %>
       <option><%= link_to "#{shop.shop_domain}", admin_path(shop.id) %> </option>
     <% end %> 
   </select>
  </form>
<div>`
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong? Please advise.

Comment: 1st thing to do is check the value of `@shops` (e.g.`logger.debug "@shops is: #{@shops}"`, or in the template `<%= debug @shops %>`)

Comment: Actually, It is showing a shop_domains in the search but when I click, it is not redirected to the admin path.

Comment: So the HTML is rendering correctly, but you would like to be redirected to the corresponding link when you choose that option in the select menu. Correct?

Comment: Yes,Absolutely!

Comment: Add this to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` or wherever you have your JS: `$("#mySelect").on("change", function(){ window.location = $(this).val(); });` replacing `mySelect` with an appropriate selector.

Comment: Where is it redirected? Is the link working?

Comment: No, The link is not working @Jeremie

Comment: @MenporulPoriyalan - did my soln work?